# In the code below is it a good idea to make the current node available for garbage collection?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm using the code below in Java to remove duplicate data from a linked list and my question is whether it is a good idea for me to explicitly set current.next = null i.e. current will be the duplicate data so I set the previous node's next to current's next but current to be deleted in java would mean make it available for gc. So, do i really need to explicitly set it ?

```
public void removeDuplicates()
{
    HashSet<Integer> nodeSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Node previous = this;
    Node current = previous;
    while(current!=null)
    {
         if(!nodeSet.contains(current.data))
         {
             nodeSet.add(current.data);
             previous = current;
             current = current.next;
         }
        else
         {
             previous.next = current.next;
             current.next = null;
             current = previous.next;

         }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

if your node is unreachable, than it's `next` node will also be unreachable(assuming that it only had 1 parent)

Comment: Not actually true with generational GC, so it can actually make sense - the standard implementation nulls out fields in some situations just for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as `current` becomes unreachable, it will make zero difference what objects are reachable from it. So no, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! You hit the nail on the head. The set to null of current is overwritten anyway when you set its value on the next run through. Since you only care about 'current' when it has a value hen you don't need to worry about setting it to null when you aren't using it. The GC will do its job when the method (and its variables) go out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't have a negative effect, no.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is sometimes done, among other things by the standard library code itself is because the underlying assumption "If an object isn't pointed to by any other it'll be collected in the next GC step" is wrong on modern JVMs.

As soon as the `current` node is in the old generation, its next pointer will be considered part of the rootset for young GC runs, which in turn means that this may cause several young nodes that were also removed from the list to also not be collected, which means they also get into the old generation. In the end this can lead to larger old generations, more rootpointers and fewer objects being collected in the young GC - all bad things.

Well that's the theory at last and some quite clever people ascribe to it, whether the effect is really noticeable is another thing - haven't run any tests about this.